# Android studio key, moving SDK's from App Inventor

Tags: android, android-studio, key

I made an app with App Inventor and now have moved over to Android Studio. when I was ready to release the new app it gave me errors about the new key. and the thumbprint. is there any way to transfer that key and thumbprint to my new android studio project? Or will I just have to make a new app listing all together? If there is a way, where shall I put the key, I am new to Android Studio.

```
    Upload failed
You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to your previous APKs. You must use the same certificate. Your existing APKs are signed with the certificate(s) with fingerprint(s):
[ SHA1: CC:95:0B:5F:5F:CF:60:35:62:4D:3C:B2:90:38:EE:D4:E1:24:83:7D ]
and the certificate(s) used to sign the APK you uploaded have fingerprint(s):
[ SHA1: 6C:88:E5:92:E3:D0:4D:1E:44:08:28:66:0D:F3:24:43:9C:67:DA:9F ]
Your APK needs to have the package name appinventor.ai_ryan3018.MLG_Soundboard.
You need to use a different version code for your APK because you already have one with version code 1.
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with AppInventor, but the first thing I would do is rename the package name to the previous package name, increment the version code to an integer that hasn't been previously used, and try that. For all we know, AppInventor might be using the same location for the key as android's. But if doesn't, then yes, move the key to the new location (but keep some backups in case you make a mistake). What OS are you using? For linux, I think the location is a folder inside an hidden folder called .android/ or something like .ssh/ inside your personal home directory.

Comment: I am currently using windows 7. Also thank you for the reply, will test it out